# Is it possible to make smooth shading that really is flat shading

Tags: shaders

Or How to make smooth shading look like flag shading.

When I export the face sets as .abc file, in my application, the acceptable shading format is smooth shading automatic.

Even I set flat shading in blender, viewpoint, the exported .abc file is smooth shading.

So, my question is is it possible to modify .abc file or do something like normal edit in blender that make smooth shading looks like flat shading.

Something like creating some fake smooth shading parameters/data that actually is flat shading parameters/data to export to the .abc file and then feed to my application.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your normal are flipped. In Edit-mode choose Mesh > Normals > Flip. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Jaco I think it's not the problem of Normal related with Flip，I've seen the normal color as Green, and I'v reset or recalculated the normal.

Comment: Aha, is it possible to share the blend-file? Thtat would make it easier to check where your problem might be.